# Is there any way to cancel deleting an index in Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, gql

I vacuumed some unneeded indexes from my Appengine python project but removed one that I should not have. When I try to update that index now I get an error saying "Index being deleted cannot be (re)built until it is completely deleted." The deletion of that index has been running for more than 12 hours now and it isn't clear that anything is actually happening. I see that the index has about 600,000 entries holding 80MB.

How long should this delete take? And is there any way to start rebuilding the index any sooner. This part of my app is effectively broken until the index is rebuilt.

**UPDATE-** This index still won't delete, it's been a full day. I've had to close of part of the site because I can't rebuild that index. Help.

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to solve this problem? I am having the same issue now. The indexes I changed are refreshing forever and nothing works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open an Production issue here:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue